# Free : Invalid Size : Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I want to free a malloc by using valgrind :

I receive this error :

```
MCM : 1900
free(): invalid size
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Here is the code I compile :

```
char test[6][10] = {"MCM", "MCML", "MCMLXXXV", "MCMXC", "MM", "MMVI"};
 int size[] = {3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 4}; 

 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {   
     char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size[i]);
     a = test[i];
     int result = convert(a, roman, arabe, size[i]);
     printf("%s : %d\n",a ,result);
     free(a);
 }
```

and by using :

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./roman
```

I receive this message :

```
==23809== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23809== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23809== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23809== Command: ./roman
==23809== 
MCM : 1900
==23809== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23809==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23809==    by 0x108B45: main (roman.c:76)
==23809==  Address 0x1fff0003d0 is on thread 1's stack
==23809==  in frame #1, created by main (roman.c:47)
==23809== 
MCML : 1950
MCMLXXXV : 1985
MCMXC : 1990
MM : 2000
MMVI : 2006
MCM      = 1900
MCML     = 1950
MCMLXXXV = 1985
MCMXC    = 1990
MM       = 2000
MMVI     = 2006
==23809== 
==23809== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23809==     in use at exit: 26 bytes in 6 blocks
==23809==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,050 bytes allocated
==23809== 
==23809== 26 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==23809==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23809==    by 0x108ABE: main (roman.c:72)
==23809== 
==23809== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23809==    definitely lost: 26 bytes in 6 blocks
==23809==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809== 
==23809== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23809== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

From what I see, there are four parts :

```
==23809== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23809==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23809==    by 0x108B45: main (roman.c:76)
==23809==  Address 0x1fff0003d0 is on thread 1's stack
==23809==  in frame #1, created by main (roman.c:47)
==23809==
```

I see that my error is line 76 :

```
free(a)
```

I don't know how to solve this.

And I don't really understand the HEAP SUMMARY and the LEAK SUMMARY :
what does it correspond to ?
HEAP SUMMARY :

```
==23809== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23809==     in use at exit: 26 bytes in 6 blocks 
==23809==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,050 bytes allocated
==23809== 
==23809== 26 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==23809==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23809==    by 0x108ABE: main (roman.c:72)
```

LEAK SUMMARY :

```
==23809== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23809==    definitely lost: 26 bytes in 6 blocks
==23809==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23809==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

And the conclusion :

```
==23809== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23809== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Can someone explain those four parts please ?

Comment: Here `a = test[i];` `a` is reassigned with non-dynamic memory i.e `a` no longer holds dynamic memory hence `free(a)` is invalid & same is detected by valgrind. Also `a = test[i];` causing memory leak as after this no object is holding the previously allocated dynamic address, you lost that.

Comment: You have a memory leak here. Since you have overwritten the value of `a` you can never free it.

Comment: regarding: printf("%s : %d\n",a ,result);`   The char array in `a[]` is not NUL terminated, so trying to print the contents of `a[]` via `%s` will result in undefined behavior.  Suggest allocating one more char in the call to `malloc()` and using `strcpy()` to copy an entry in `test[]` to `a[]`

Comment: regarding the array: `size[]`  Much better (and less error prone) to use `strlen()` on the current entry in `test[]` and eliminate the array `size[]`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size[i]);`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  2) the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that this:

```
 a = test[i];
```

copies the string into the memory pointed to by `a`.  But in fact it just discards the pointer stored in `a` and replaces that with a pointer to `test`.  So you've lost (leaked) your allocated memory, and therefore `free`ing it is an error.

Answer (score 1):

`a = test[i]` doesn't copy the contents of the array, only the address of the array. Use the [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) function to copy data.

```
// you need to allocate size + 1 bytes if you want to copy the trailing '\0'
char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size[i] + 1));
memcpy(a, test[i], size[i] + 1);
```

In case of character sequences you can also use [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

```
// (size + 1) bytes long destination buffer is mandatory
char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size[i] + 1));
strcpy(a, test[i]);
```

Comment: Or on POSIX.1-2001 compliant systems, use the much more convenient `char *a = strdup(test[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! it works ;)
For the community, I'm adding the programm for a conversion roman-arabic numbers :
I first post the answer and after all the code :

Answer :

```
char test[6][10] = {"MCM", "MCML", "MCMLXXXV", "MCMXC", "MM", "MMVI"};
 int size[] = {3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 4}; 

 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {   
     char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size[i]);
     a = memcpy(a, test[i], size[i]);
     int result = convert(a, roman, arabe, size[i]);
     printf("%s : %d\n",a ,result);
     free(a);
 }
```

All the code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int r_to_a(char roman[], int arabe[], char c)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
     {
         if (c == roman[i])
         {
             return arabe[i];
         }
     }

     return -1;
 }

int convert(char tab[], char roman[], int arabe[], int size)
 {
     int result = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         if (i > 0 && r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i]) < r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i + 1]))
         {
             result += r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i + 1]) - r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i]);
             i++;
             //printf("RESULT : %d\n", result);
         }
         else if (i > 0 && r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i]) >= r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i - 1]))
         {
             result += r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i]);
             //printf("RESULT : %d\n", result);
         }
         else
         {
             result += r_to_a(roman, arabe, tab[i]);
             //printf("RESULT : %d\n", result);
         }
     }
     return result;
 }


 int main()
 {
     char roman[7] = {'I','V','X','L','C','D','M'};
     int  arabe[7] = { 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};

     char test[6][10] = {"MCM", "MCML", "MCMLXXXV", "MCMXC", "MM", "MMVI"};
     int size[] = {3, 4, 8, 5, 2, 4};

     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
         char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size[i]);
         a = memcpy(a, test[i], size[i]);
         int result = convert(a, roman, arabe, size[i]);
         printf("%s : %d\n",a ,result);
         free(a);
     }

     printf("\n\nMCM      = 1900\nMCML     = 1950\nMCMLXXXV = 1985\nMCMXC    = 1990\nMM       = 2000\nMMVI     = 2006\n");

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome! Consider upvoting good answers and accepting a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version of the main, more cleaner :

```
int main()
{ 
     char roman[7] = {'I','V','X','L','C','D','M'};
     int  arabe[7] = { 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};

     char test[6][10] = {"MCM", "MCML", "MCMLXXXV", "MCMXC", "MM", "MMVI"};

     int test_length = sizeof(test) / sizeof(*test);
     int *size = malloc(sizeof(int) * test_length); 
     size = return_size_tab(test, test_length);
     for (int i = 0; i < test_length; i++)
     {   
         char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size[i]);
         // memcpy de mettre les valeurs d'un tableau dans une adresse
         a = memcpy(a, test[i], size[i]);
         int result = convert(a, roman, arabe, size[i]);
         printf("%s : %d\n",a ,result);
         free(a);
     }
     free(size);   

     printf("\n\nMCM      = 1900\nMCML     = 1950\nMCMLXXXV = 1985\nMCMXC    = 1990\nMM       = 2000\nMMVI     = 2006\n");

     return 0;
 }
```

with the added function "return_size_tab" :

```
int *return_size_tab(char tab[][10], int test_length)
{
     int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * test_length);
     for (int i = 0; i < test_length; i++)
     {
         int j = 0;
         while (tab[i][j] != '\0')
         {
             j++;
         }
         ret[i] = j;
     }
     return ret;
}
```